# Why is this a grammatically incorrect sentence? (according to the ACT)

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, sentence, conjunctions

On one of the tests, the ACT asked to pick which sentence was unacceptable.
I'm not sure why this sentence is unacceptable: "The silhouettes merge Shin's past and present and they create an exquisite meditation on Korean American Identity."

Here are the acceptable sentences:

- "The silhouettes merge Shin's past and present to create an exquisite meditation on Korean American Identity."
- "The silhouettes merge Shin's past and present. They create an exquisite meditation on Korean American Identity."
- "The silhouettes merge Shin's past and present; they create an exquisite meditation on Korean American Identity."

Comment: I think you should ask the people who wrote the test.

Comment: I agree with @HotLicks. I can't see anything wrong with it, They're probably applying some strange made-up rule that has nothing to do with what English speakers actually say.

Comment: The test setters are wrong. All sentences are acceptable. I am voting to close the question because (not your fault) it is based on false premise.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is based on a false premise that is not the questioner’s fault, so cannot be corrected to attract answers.